# SpringBootTest failed to load ApplicationContext due to 'Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started'

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, testcontainers, embedded-postgres

I am using `org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.17.2` for my integration tests. I also use `io.zonky.test:embedded-database-spring-test:2.1.1` for unit tests that require a repository.

A database-related part of `application-it.yml`

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  flyway:
    user: flyway
    password: password
    schemas: public
    placeholders:
      user: ${spring.datasource.username}
```

BaseIT.java:

```
@ActiveProfiles("it")
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
public abstract class BaseIT {

    //...
    // Some services injections
    //...

    static MockWebServer server;

    @Container
    public static PostgreSQLContainer<?> POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER =
            new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:14.3-alpine")
                    .withDatabaseName("db")
                    .withUsername("postgres")
                    .withPassword("postgres")
                    .withInitScript("init.sql");

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", POSTGRESQL_CONTAINER::getPassword);
    }

}
```

MyIT.java:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "app.scheduling.enable=false"
})
public class MyIT extends BaseIT {

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {
        server = new MockWebServer();
        server.start(8999);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void afterEachTest() {
        repository.deleteAll();
    }

    //...
    // Some tests
    //...
}
```

MyUnitTest.java

```
@Import({
        Service.class
})
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate"
})
@ActiveProfiles("it")
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase(type = AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase.DatabaseType.POSTGRES)
public class MyUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    //...
    // Some tests
    //...
}
```

So, when I run MyIT the following exception occurs. Attaching full stacktrace:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.forEachDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:90)
    at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.resetDatabases(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:58)
    at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.beforeTestClass(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:34)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestClass(TestContextManager.java:213)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeAll(SpringExtension.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:381)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:381)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:205)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
        at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.forEachDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:90)
        at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.resetDatabases(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:58)
        at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.afterTestClass(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:54)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestClass(TestContextManager.java:492)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterAll(SpringExtension.java:122)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$16(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:447)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$17(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:447)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:447)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:229)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:80)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:161)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:161)
        ... 47 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [some.group.artifact.ApplicationSpringBootMainClass]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration
        at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610)
        at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:111)
        at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812)
        at java.base@17.0.2/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809)
        at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780)
        at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
        at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
        at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
        at app//org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
        at app//org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
        at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
        at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
        at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414)
        at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
        at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136)
        at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        ... 63 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:372)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:272)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600)
        ... 81 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:174)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerState.getMappedPort(ContainerState.java:148)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(PostgreSQLContainer.java:84)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicValuesPropertySource.getProperty(DynamicValuesPropertySource.java:43)
        at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:123)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.findPropertyValue(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:97)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:74)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:60)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:594)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseCondition.hasDataSourceUrlProperty(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:153)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseCondition.getMatchOutcome(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:136)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
        ... 87 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [some.group.artifact.ApplicationSpringBootMainClass]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration
    at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610)
    at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:111)
    at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812)
    at java.base@17.0.2/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809)
    at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780)
    at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
    at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
    at app//org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:372)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:174)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerState.getMappedPort(ContainerState.java:148)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(PostgreSQLContainer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicValuesPropertySource.getProperty(DynamicValuesPropertySource.java:43)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.findPropertyValue(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:60)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:594)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseCondition.hasDataSourceUrlProperty(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseCondition.getMatchOutcome(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 85 more
```

In other words, this chain of calls:

```
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.forEachDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:90)
```

... leads to these calls:

```
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:174)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerState.getMappedPort(ContainerState.java:148)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(PostgreSQLContainer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicValuesPropertySource.getProperty(DynamicValuesPropertySource.java:43)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85)
```

but the container is not UP at this moment (as specified in the exception's message).
Removing `io.zonky.test:embedded-database-spring-test:2.1.1` from dependecides helps to resolve this since `EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener` is no longer present in the classpath.

How can "disable" all stuff related with `io.zonky.test:embedded-database-spring-test:2.1.1` during my integration tests? Or at least its `EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener` that I don't need in my IT.

Thanks!

Comment: Since `io.zonky.test:embedded-database-spring-test:2.1.1` is also based on Testcontainers, I would advise against mixing the libraries directly. Is in unclear to me, why you don't use Testcontainers directly for your use cases.

Comment: @KevinWittek unit tests that use `io.zonky.test:embedded-database-spring-test:2.1.1` appeared before IT with Testcontainers was created. In my unit test, I tried to use `@DataJpaTest` but with PostgreSQL instead of H2. Yeah, currently, to get rid of this problem, I use `PostgreSQLContainer` in my unit test. This works fine.